# The event is fired on GTM but not found on GA4

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have a SaaS application where I'd like to track when some buttons on landing page are clicked.

One of them, it has been successfully fired (see attached file) using `datalayer.push` as seen on GTM, however, I don't know where can I find how many times this event has been fired on Google Analytics 4.

When accessing `Engagement/Events` menu on GTA4, I can see the "button_click" event, but I can't find the "botao_teste_gratuitamente_header"

Why? Any help would be really appreciated!

[image]

Comment: It is controlled by your tag `Button Click`. Is the event name setting "button_click" but you added an event parameter?

Comment: you mean on datalayer request? 

this is the call: `var dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'botao_teste_gratuitamente_header',
  'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
  'gtm.containerId': 'GTM-XXXXX'
});`

Comment: Can we take a look on the ga4 event tag?

Comment: I think I attached now what you mean @darrelltw haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event name in your datalayer.push() is pushed to the data layer on your website. You then listens for this event in the data layer with a custom event trigger from Google Tag Manager. However none of this affects GA4.

It is the tag you have created ("Button Click") that sends the event to GA4, and the event name you choose inside this tag is the one that will be displayed as the event name in GA4.

The event name "botao_teste_gratuitamente_header" hasn't been sent to GA4, if you do not add it to the "Button Click" event in GTM. It is only sent to your data layer.

What you could do is add "botao_teste_gratuitamente_header" as a parameter in the tag like below:

[image: The button click tag]

This will be hardcoded, so all clicks that triggers this tag will have the parameter "botao_teste_gratuitamente_header". You could also use more dynamic parameters like the built in "{{Click Text}}" to get the text of any element that is clicked as a parameter. Remember to register your parameters as custom dimensions in GA4.

If you want to set the event name itself as "botao_teste_gratuitamente_header" you would need to add that as the event name in your "Button Click" tag, instead of "button_click".

Comment: IT WORKEEEEEEEEED!!! thanks a lot!

Comment: damn, in fact, it is only working when using gtm_debug. any idea what it could be?

Comment: Did you end up using "botao_teste_gratuitamente_header" as a parameter or event name?

Comment: this tutorial helped to figure it out. basically, when I set the Page Path to "/" it worked finally =). thanks!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JOFtjLpwBLE